# When does a C# List double its capacity?

Tags: c#, list, generics

It's my understanding that when a List in C# hits its capacity, it doubles said capacity. So a List with a capacity of 100 will double to 200.

My question is: does this happen when the 100th item is added or when the 101st item is added?

In other words, if I know that a List will have up to 100 items and no more, should I set the capacity to 100 or to 101 in order to prevent the cost of doubling?

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: As far as I know (from looking into the .NET source code) it happens when the capacity would otherwise be exceeded, i.e. in your example when the 101st item is about to be added. You can pass a value for the capacity to the List constructor in order to hand tailor its capacity to exactly match the count of items needed. In your case you would set the capacity to 100, not 101.

Comment: See this source code from NET Framework: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#9cc11588bffd57c1 (Assuming it's the same logic in Core ...)

Comment: Apart from anything else, the example you specified could have been tested in a couple of minutes with a few lines of code. You never need to ask us what you can simply test for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=net-8.0#remarks) states:

> `Capacity` is always greater than or equal to Count. If `Count` exceeds `Capacity` while adding elements, the capacity is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements.

For completeness, here is how it is [currently implemented](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,196) (but keep in mind this is an implementation detail). As you can see, the reallocation occurs if you try to add and `Count` equals `Capacity`.

If you already know how many items you're going to have in the list, set the list's capacity to that amount. Ideally, you'd even create the list with the right capacity from the start:

```
var list = new List<T>(capacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the **List** class increases its capacity dynamically as elements are added. The capacity doubling occurs when the **101st** item is added, **not when the 100th** item is reached.

So, if you know that your list will have up to 100 items and no more, you can set the capacity to 100 to prevent unnecessary capacity doubling.